# Get text from different fields in multiple divs of same name

Tags: c#, user-interface, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get text,timestamp and name from all the row in a webpage, and they are of same name.I Intend to put them all in a txt doc. e.g

```
<div data-tid="Name" dir="auto"><div>Text1</div></div>...<div data-tid="TimeStamp" dir="auto"><div>Text1</div>....</div><div data-tid="message" dir="auto"><div>Text1</div></div>
.....
<div data-tid="Name" dir="auto"><div>Text1</div></div>...<div data-tid="TimeStamp" dir="auto"><div>Text1</div>....</div><div data-tid="message" dir="auto"><div>Text1</div></div>
....
<div data-tid="Name" dir="auto"><div>Text1</div></div>...<div data-tid="TimeStamp" dir="auto"><div>Text1</div>....</div><div data-tid="message" dir="auto"><div>Text1</div></div>
```

What should the loop look like if i need to have name and timestamp along with message? Tried that

```
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> chatRow = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='message']/div"));
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> TimeStamp = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='TimeStamp']/div"));
IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> Name = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='Name']/div"));
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < chatRow.Count && j < nameRow.Count; i++, j++)
{
                 GetAttribute("innerHTML");
}}
```

Comment: Instead of the handcrafted HTML update the question with the relevant text based HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop in question works perfectly, there was a little issue in calling function only :) take the question as solution